# Slash in abbreviations for example j/k or w/e

Tags: abbreviations

I was wondering why people use a slash in abbrevations for example `w/e` or `j/k` (`whatever` and `just kidding`). I've seen them with and without a slash and I am actually interested to know what the slash means, in German we don't use slashes in abbrevations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is any reason for it other than people find it useful and so it's a convention that has arisen.

For a list of different type of 'slash abbreviations' see here
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slash_(punctuation)#Abbreviation

As far as *w/e*, I think that the slash is useful because it distinguishes it from the first person plural pronoun *we*.